# If checkbox checked, instantly alert

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling

So, my goal is this: if the checkbox is checked by the user, do something (let's say just an alert). Here's my code, that is not working:

```
function validate() {
    if (document.getElementById('LetterNeed').checked) {
        alert("checked");
    } else {
        alert("You didn't check it! Let me check it for you.");
    }
}    

<input type="checkbox" name="LetterNeed" id="LetterNeed">Not important</span>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: where are you calling the `validate()` function?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: If you wrap the checkbox in a label element or connect the two with the "for" attribute of the label, you can check/uncheck it by clicking on _either_ the box or the label, which provides a much larger target to click/tap on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call the `validate` function on `change` of the checkbox state.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="LetterNeed" id="LetterNeed" onchange="return validate()">Not important</span>
//                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

**OR**

```
document.getElementById('LetterNeed').addEventListener('change', validate);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/qjjg74nv/)

Answer (score 2):

**Old Approach**

Call the <kbd>**`validate()`**</kbd> function in the <kbd>**`<input>`**</kbd> tag

```js
function validate() {
    if (document.getElementById('LetterNeed').checked) {
        alert("checked");
    } else {
        alert("You didn't check it! Let me check it for you.");
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="LetterNeed" id="LetterNeed" onclick="validate()">Not important</span>
```

**Event Handling approach**

```js
function validate() {
  if (this.checked) {
    alert("checked");
  } else {
    alert("You didn't check it! Let me check it for you.");
  }
}

document.getElementById('LetterNeed').addEventListener('click', validate);
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="LetterNeed" id="LetterNeed"><span>Not important</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

on the other hand you can add `eventlistener` on `DOMContentLoaded` as below:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
      document.querySelector('#LetterNeed').addEventListener('change', validate);
});
```

A function to `validate`

```
function validate(e){
     if(e.target.checked)
     { 
        alert("Checked"); 
     } 
     else{ 
        alert("Not checked"); 
     } 
}
```

Comment: Within the listener, *this* will reference the element so forget *e.target* and use *this*. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

try these changes :

```
function validate(aCheckBox) {
  if (aCheckBox.checked) {
    alert("checked");
  } else {
    alert("You didn't check it! Let me check it for you.");
  }
}    

<input type="checkbox" name="LetterNeed" id="LetterNeed" onclick="validate(this)">Not important</input>
```