# how to select all checkbox, then click accept button, then pop up a message

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i want to ask. does anybody know how to select all checkbox, 
then click accept button, then pop up a message below. my friend said i need to bring the id. but i don't know how to do it

I need to do javascript to pop up the message after i click a button. i already make the button, but i don't know how to link all of it.

(THIS IS THE CODE FOR POP UP MESSAGE)

```
<!-- Common Accept Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="common_accept_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
aria- 
labelledby="common_accept_modal" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-popout modal-dialog-centered" 
role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="block block-themed block-transparent mb-0">
    <div class="block-header bg-primary-dark pt-3">
      <h3 class="block-title">Confirm Accept</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content font-size-sm">
      <form id="common_accept_form" action="process/osa_action.php" 
method="post">
        <div class="row items-push p-0 m-0">
          <p class="">Are you sure you want to accept this application?</p>
          <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control input-sm bg- 
white mb-1 text-grey" 
disabled />
          <input type="text" name="prog" class="form-control input-sm bg- 
white mb-1 text-grey" 
disabled />
            <select class="form-control input-sm" name="oltype" required>
              <option value=''>Offer Type</option>
              <option value='1'>Letter of Offer (Foundation)</option>
              <option value='2'>Letter of Offer (Degree)</option>
              <option value='3'>Conditional Offer Letter</option>
            </select>
         <input type="text" name="email" hidden/>
          <input type="text" name="proc" hidden />
          <input type="text" name="appid" hidden />
          <input type="text" name="optid" hidden />
          <input type="text" name="progid" hidden />
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content block-content-full text-right">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" 
form="common_accept_form">Continue</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

(This is the button and select all checkbox that i do)

```
<div>
<button type="button" name="btn_accept" id="btn_accept" class="btn btn- 
accept">Accept Application</button>
            <div class="float-right">
              <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" id="btnSearch" placeholder="Search..">
                <div class="input-group-append">
                  <span class="input-group-text">
                    <i class="fa fa-search fa-1x"></i>
                  </span>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
            <table class="table table-vcenter js-dataTable-buttons">
              <thead class="thead-light">
                <tr>
                  <th><input type='checkbox' id='select_all' 
onclick="selectAll()">Select</th>
                  <th>#</th>
                  <th width="7%">Session</th>
                  <th width="25%">Applicant Details</th>
                  <th>Progress</th>
                  <th>Programme</th>
                  <th>Remarks</th>
                  <th class="text-center">Action</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <?php
                $k=0;
                for ($i=1; $i<=$total_app; $i++) {
                  if (isset($app_deptid[$i]) and $app_deptid[$i]==$sch[$m] 
and $app_display[$i]==1) { $k++;
                    ?>
                      <tr>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="selectall" 
class="check_invoice"/></td>
                        <td><?=$k?></td>
                        <td><?=$app_acas[$i]?></td>
                        <td><?=$app_details[$i]?></td>
                        <td><?=$app_progres[$i]?></td>
                        <td><?=$app_program[$i]?></td>
                        <td><?=$app_remarks[$i]?><br><br><? 
=$app_reasonremarks[$i]?></td>
                        <td class="text-center"><?=$app_btn[$i]?></td>
                      </tr>
                    <?php
                  }
                }
                for ($i=1; $i<=$total_app; $i++) {
                  if (isset($app_deptid[$i]) and 
$app_deptid[$i]=="Unassigned" and $app_display[$i]==1) { $k++;
                  ?>
                    <tr>
                      <td><input type="checkbox" name="selectall" 
class="check_invoice"/></td>
                      <td><?=$k?></td>
                      <td><?=$app_acas[$i]?></td>
                      <td><?=$app_details[$i]?></td>
                      <td><?=$app_progres[$i]?></td>
                      <td><?=$app_program[$i]?></td>
                      <td><?=$app_remarks[$i]?><br><br><? 
=$app_reasonremarks[$i]?></td>
                      <td class="text-center"><?=$app_btn[$i]?></td>
                    </tr>
                  <?php
```

(This is the javascript for select all checkbox)

```
<script>
function selectAll() {
    var blnChecked = document.getElementById("select_all").checked;
    var check_invoices = document.getElementsByClassName("check_invoice");
    var intLength = check_invoices.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < intLength; i++) {
        var check_invoice = check_invoices[i];
        check_invoice.checked = blnChecked;
    }
}

</script>
```

so i don't know how to continue. when i click the accept application button, it will pop up the message.

Comment: Yes, this seems fairly straightforward but without code or seeing what you have tried so far it is impossible to provide definitive answer. Add your code would be a great start

Comment: Please review [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @RamRaider I already make a correction to my question.

Comment: I can't see any checkboxes in the above HTML or an `accept` button

Comment: @RamRaider sorry. i already add that code.

Comment: The checkboxes within the loop(s) will all be identical and none have any values. Is there a point to these?

Comment: @RamRaider actually i am not sure whether what i am doing right now is right or not. i just try doing the code based on what i search. i am new to php. hope you can help me

Answer (score 0):

i encounter like that when the checkbox is being select i want to pop up alert if that was you like here is the solution that i find. https://stackoverflow.com/a/30979941/12875957

Comment: no. it not this way. i dont want a simple alert message. i want to pop up the message that i already create

Answer (score 0):

I ought to state that I have little knowledge of jQuery nor of using the `modal` popups so can offer no guidance there. With respect to the selection of all checkboxes and then subsequent button click perhaps the following example might help. The HTML is a rough approximation of that from the question in that there are a selection of checkboxes that must can all be selected/deselected simply by clicking the master checkbox. Once that checkbox has been checked the `accept` button is enabled which, when pressed, uses the `modal` content somehow. In the below the `modal` content is inserted to the document body using `insertAdjacentHTML`

The `modal` content here is stored away in a template so that it is out of the regular flow of html for this demo... no doubt it would be hidden and it's appearance & position controlled by CSS & possibly javascript.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',(e)=>{
 let modal;
 const checked=[];
 const minchecked=2;
 
 const chkbox=document.querySelector('input[name="selectall"][type="checkbox"]');
 const bttn=document.querySelector('button[name="btn_accept"]');
 const template=document.querySelector('template#popup');
 const colInput=document.querySelectorAll('[type="checkbox"]:not( [name="selectall"] )');
 
 const changehandler=function(e){
  Array.from( colInput ).forEach(chk=>{
   chk.checked=this.checked;
   bttn.disabled=!this.checked;
  });
 };
 const clickhandler=function(e){
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforebegin', template.innerHTML );
 };
 const updatehandler=function(e){
  if( this.checked )checked.push( this );
  else checked.splice( checked.indexOf( this ),1 );
  
  /* If you want to enable the button */
  bttn.disabled = checked.length <= minchecked;
  
  /* if you want to popup the message automatically */
  if( checked.length >= minchecked )clickhandler.call( this, e );
  else {
   if( modal=document.getElementById('common_accept_modal') ){
    modal.parentNode.removeChild( modal )
   }
  }
 };
 
 
 
 chkbox.addEventListener( 'change', changehandler );
 bttn.addEventListener( 'click', clickhandler );
 
 Array.from( colInput ).forEach( chk=>{
  chk.addEventListener('change',updatehandler)
 })
});
```

```html
<form method='post'>

 <label>Select All<input type='checkbox' name='selectall' /></label>

 <div class='inv_chkboxes'>
  <input type="checkbox" name="inv_chk[]" value="1" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="inv_chk[]" value="2" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="inv_chk[]" value="3" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="inv_chk[]" value="4" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="inv_chk[]" value="5" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="inv_chk[]" value="6" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="inv_chk[]" value="7" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="inv_chk[]" value="8" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="inv_chk[]" value="9" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="inv_chk[]" value="10" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="inv_chk[]" value="11" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="inv_chk[]" value="12" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="inv_chk[]" value="13" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="inv_chk[]" value="14" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="inv_chk[]" value="15" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="inv_chk[]" value="16" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="inv_chk[]" value="17" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="inv_chk[]" value="18" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="inv_chk[]" value="19" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="inv_chk[]" value="20" />
 </div>
 
 <button type="button" name="btn_accept" class="btn btn-accept" disabled>Accept Application</button>
 
 <template id='popup'>
  <!-- Common Accept Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="common_accept_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="common_accept_modal" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-popout modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="block block-themed block-transparent mb-0">
      <div class="block-header bg-primary-dark pt-3">
       <h3 class="block-title">Confirm Accept</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="block-content font-size-sm">
       <form id="common_accept_form" action="process/osa_action.php" method="post">
        <div class="row items-push p-0 m-0">
         <p>Are you sure you want to accept this application?</p>
         <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control input-sm bg-white mb-1 text-grey" disabled />
         <input type="text" name="prog" class="form-control input-sm bg-white mb-1 text-grey" disabled />
         <select class="form-control input-sm" name="oltype" required>
          <option selected disabled hidden>Offer Type
          <option value='1'>Letter of Offer (Foundation)
          <option value='2'>Letter of Offer (Degree)
          <option value='3'>Conditional Offer Letter
         </select>
         <input type="text" name="email" hidden/>
         <input type="text" name="proc" hidden />
         <input type="text" name="appid" hidden />
         <input type="text" name="optid" hidden />
         <input type="text" name="progid" hidden />
        </div>
       </form>
      </div>
      <div class="block-content block-content-full text-right">
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" form="common_accept_form">Continue</button>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>   
 </template>
 
</form>
```

Comment: thank you very much. it really help me a lot. but how can i change when only select one or two then pop up the message?

Comment: So you wish to ignore the `"select all"` approach and use a minimum number of checked checkboxes to initialise the button?

Comment: not that i want to ignore. i mean that, even if the user only click one or two checkbox, they can still click the "accept" button. when i try to run the code, i just can only click select all button, then only after that i can click the accept button. so i want the user to able to click select all and a few checkbox, then they can click the "accept" button. thank you for helping me

Comment: i still cannot popup the message

Comment: you should try the modified version here (changed yesterday.) allows user to select 2 checkboxes and then invoke the modal or "select all" and click/..... how the `modal` is opened in reality is unknown to me - I do not use jQuery so can not guide ou - you will work that out for yourself. Also - consider upvoting if it helped